# Anchor link page scroll WITH href link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have some simple links that play Youtube videos in a div named videoPlayer (via a jQuery video player)...

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aaaaa" target="videoPlayer">
```

I also have a link which scrolls to the same div on the page like this...

```
<a class="btn" href="#videoPlayer">WATCH VIDEO</a>
```

Is it possible to create a link that both scrolls to #videoPlayer AND plays the Youtube video when it gets there? Basically, I need BOTH above hrefs to work when the link is clicked.

Comment: doesn't the first link will redirect your page? then what is the purpose of second link'

Comment: And shouldn't the first link be either a `<video>` tag or an `<iframe>` tag? Are you literally just directing the vistors off to YouTube? It's certainly possible to achieve what you're after, but you'll have to specify your constraints. Like I'm assuming you're using something like FancyBox to display the video in a popup?

Comment: Don't get confused by the Youtube stuff. It loads in a jQuery player which is contained in the videoPlayer div. So basically, one link loads the video and plays it, the other link scrolls down to the part of the page containing it.

Comment: updated the question @ObsidianAge

Comment: Your question is still incredibly unclear and still doesn't provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In even simpler terms, I need a solution that makes a single link act like the href here - ahref=#videoPlayer AND https://www.youtube.com/embed/aaaaa

Comment: @lowercase See my answer [**Plunker 2**](http://embed.plnkr.co/sKwN8RSGEcCl4AGVQfIn/) . It does exactly what you described all in one link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Play YouTube videos with the `target/name` attribute link

1.- Tags:

1. one `<a>`
2. one `<frame>`

2.- `<a>` Attributes:

1. `href="https://https://www.youtube.com/embed/`**VideoID**`?autoplay=1&controls=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&showinfo=0"`
2. `target="`**iframe[name]**`

3.- `<iframe>` Attributes:

1. `src="about:blank"`
2. `name="`**AnyString**`"`

   - In HTML4 if you give `<a>` a `[name]` attribute (it's now an anchor) and another `<a>` a `[href]` with the value of the other's `[name]`, they are then linked.
   - In HTML5 that no longer applies -- `#id` can only be used for the previously mentioned behavior.
   - An `<iframe>` given a `[name]` can be targeted by an `<a>` with the `[target]` attribute with the value of said `<iframe>`s `[name]`. When the `<a>` is clicked, the `<iframe>`'s `src` will change to the `href` value of the `<a>`.
   - `<a>` tags are interactive elements. An interactive element is invalid and will not function if nested within another interactive element. Interactive elements are `<label>`, `<button>`, `<input>`, etc.
   - So to answer the question:

> *"Is it possible to create a link that both scrolls to #videoPlayer AND plays the Youtube video when it gets there?"*

The answer: Not without JavaScript, because an `<a>` needs the `[href]` and the `[target]` attribute to activate an `<iframe>`. An `<a>` needs it's `[href]` to jump to anywhere even in HTML4. Nesting an `<a>` within an `<a>`, `<label>`,`<button>` etc. will not work either.

If you want:

> *"...a link that both scrolls to #videoPlayer AND plays the Youtube video..."*

add this to the `<a>`:

`onclick="window.onscroll(0,`**Number of pixels -n = up, n = down**`)"`

See **Demo 2**

**YouTube rarely works on SO. If you want to see a working demo go to the [Plunker 1](http://embed.plnkr.co/79qjeukOD0kYIMVIRalp/) and [Plunker 2](http://embed.plnkr.co/sKwN8RSGEcCl4AGVQfIn/)**.

#### Demo 1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    a,
    iframe {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4r7wHMg5Yjg?autoplay=1&controls=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" target='yt'>Honey Badgers</a>


  <iframe id="yt" name='yt' width="320" height="180" src="about:blank" frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

[**Plunker 2**](http://embed.plnkr.co/sKwN8RSGEcCl4AGVQfIn/)

#### Demo 2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style>
    a,
    iframe {
      display: block;
    }
    
    iframe {
      margin-bottom: 300px
    }
    
    main {
      height: 700px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4r7wHMg5Yjg?autoplay=1&controls=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" target='yt' onclick='window.scrollTo(0,1000);'>Honey Badgers</a>

  <main></main>

  <iframe id="yt" name='yt' width="320" height="180" src="about:blank" frameborder='1' allowfullscreen></iframe>



</body>

</html>
```